# Can we have a multiple color.xml file for a project in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-theme, android-styles

I am working on an application where there are some set of material colors for each activity. I have all material colors in separate xml- . My Concern is, In my style.xml, I need to call the respective file. For E.g, if color is **Yellow**, I should call the Yellow Material Colors, if the color is **Green**, I should call the Green material Colors. How to call this in style.xml

Comment: Use prefixes on the color resources (e.g., `yellow_`, `green_`). Filenames for color resources are ignored, and you have no way of telling Android "use the colors from this file that happens to have color resources".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of separate XML files, design separate styles for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ve created a separate styles already, yet how should I say to refer particular color files. I strictly don't want to put the color code in style. (ie. #232323)